# jquery split() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hopefully this is easy for someone.

I have a set of checkboxes with values 1,2,3 etc with the same name attribute (cp_bundle).

I use the following code to get a comma-delimited list of those checkboxes.

```
var hl_calling_plan_bundle = $('input[name="cp_bundle"]:checked').getCheckboxVal() || "";

jQuery.fn.getCheckboxVal = function(){
    var vals = [];
    var i = 0;
    this.each(function(){
        vals[i++] = jQuery(this).val();
    });
    return vals;
}
```

if I check the first and third checkboxes, the following will be returned:

```
1,3
```

Then, I want to run a test to see whether a particular value (e.g. "3") exists in the the returned variable

But, I can't get past the split of the variable using the following:

```
var aCallingBundle = hl_calling_plan_bundle.split(",");
```

This gives the error:

```
hl_calling_plan_bundle.split is not a function
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hl_calling_plan_bundle` is an array.  You have to use array operations on it, not string operations.

If you want to know if the value 3 is in the array, then you have to search the array for it.  There are many ways to search an array, but since you have jQuery, it's easy to use the `.inArray()` function:

```
var index = $.inArray(3, hl_calling_plan_bundle);
if (index != 1) {
    // found 3 in the array at index
}
```

Incidentally, you may want to simplify your function like this:

```
jQuery.fn.getCheckboxVal = function(){
    var vals = [];
    this.each(function(){
        vals.push(this.value);
    });
    return vals;
}
```

or this way:

```
jQuery.fn.getCheckboxVal = function(){
    return(this.map(function(){return(this.value)}).get());
}
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and I don't get the error, but I'm getting -1 every time as the index. There's something wrong with the way the array is returning from getCheckboxVal() because if I hardcode the array as [1,2,3] I start getting the correct index.

Comment: It works here http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/U8Um4/.  You may have to show your HTML for us to see what values you have set in the HTML.  You may also need to be careful about strings vs. numbers.  The HTML will produce a value that is a string which will compare properly to a number sometimes (because of implicit conversion), but not always.

Comment: OK, the solution for me was this: var index = $.inArray("3", hl_calling_plan_bundle); Note the double-quotes around the 3. Just seen your reply. Yes, it was an issue with string vs number.

Answer (score 1):

[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is a `String` method, it does not exist on an `Array`.

When you say *the following is returned `1,3`*, you may be implicitly calling the `String`'s `toString()` method, which will by default `join()` the array members with a comma. If you explicitly called `toString()`, *then* you could call `split()`, but that would be an anti pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to split the string, you can just use RegEx to search:

```
var str = '1,3,22,5';

/\b1\b/.test(str);   // true
/\b2\b/.test(str);   // false
/\b3\b/.test(str);   // true
/\b5\b/.test(str);   // true
/\b22\b/.test(str);  // true
```

---

Making it a function:

```
String.prototype.findVal = function(val){
                              var re = new RegExp('\\b' + val + '\\b');
                              re.lastIndex = 0;
                              return re.test(this);
                           };

str.findVal(2);    // false
str.findVal(22);   // true
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the checkboxes:

```
var cbs = document.getElementsByName('cp_bundle');
```

To get arrays of all values and the checked values:

```
var allValues = [];
var checkedValues = [];
for (var i=0, iLen=cbs.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  if (cbs[i].checked) checkedValues.push(cbs[i].value);
  allValues[i] = cbs[i].value;
}
```